# assigning a color for a cell not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

i am trying to set the background color for the first cell in my table view to blue for exemple but it wont work . each time i start scrolling the  blue color jumps to a different cell . i am tried these codes .

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if([[self.menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqual:@"a string"]){


    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor] ;



}

}
```

and

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell       forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

if(indexPath.row==0){


    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor] ;



}

}
```

and i tried it also in cellfro row at index path.  am i missing something ?

this is the code i am using for cellforrowatindexpath:

```
   if(indexPath.row==0){


    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor] ;



}
```

Comment: You're missing the second part. You need an else statement to cover other cases other than just your if statement. Check my post to see the solution I've got for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add also an else on the if...

```
if(indexPath.row==0){


        cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor] ;



    }
else
 cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor] ;
```

The uitableviewCell's are being reused...

Answer (score -1):

In your case the cell jumps color because cells in a tableview gets reused when scrolling to save on memory so to avoid any weird stuff from happening, you need specifically set the color for any cell.

You got the first bit done and that is to color the cell when the indexPath.row == 0 now to cover the second part:

What you need to is follow a pattern like this:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    //if its the first cell then keep it this color
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
else {
    //Any other cell keep it this color
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Why was this down voted? please when down voting post a comment explaining why. Thanks